# I can't create resources for android with react-native bundle, I get Unable to resolve module error

Tags: android, react-native

I am responsible for maintaining an application developed with React Native for 2 years. The target of the android project is set to API 30 and the client wants to update it to API 31. What I thought would be easy to change in Gradle turned out to be a headache.

I don't know how many things I've tried anymore (update react native, update gradle, install JDK11...), but I've ended up discarding the changes and cloning all the code from the repository again.

Here are the steps I now know for sure I've done:

- Install JDK11 (previously installed).
- Clone the React Native project from repository.
- Run command `npm install`.
- Update Gradle to version 7.3.3 (I have done this by opening the Android project with Android Studio).

These are the versions of the packages in packages.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "react": "17.0.2",
  "react-native": "0.67.2",
  ...
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "7.12.13",
  "@babel/runtime": "7.12.13",
  "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "1.1.0",
  "babel-jest": "25.5.1",
  "eslint": "6.8.0",
  "jest": "25.5.4",
  "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.59.0",
  "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
},
```

At this point I can run the app with the `react-native run-android` command, but no image loads. Of course, as I have cloned the project from scratch, I have to create the resources. For that I execute this command, which I have used many times in the past:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/ app/src/main/res
```

But I get this error:

```
warn Package react-native-vector-icons contains invalid configuration: "dependency.assets" is not allowed. Please verify it's properly linked using "react-native config" command and contact the package maintainers about this.
                Welcome to Metro v0.72.3
              Fast - Scalable - Integrated


error Unable to resolve module C:\Users\{myusername}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\metro-runtime\src\modules\empty-module.js from C:\DATA\Projects\iDOL\Code\{myappname}\_:

None of these files exist:
  * ..\..\..\..\..\Users\{myusername}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\metro-runtime\src\modules\empty-module.js(.native|.native.js|.js|.native.jsx|.jsx|.native.json|.json|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * ..\..\..\..\..\Users\{myusername}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\metro-runtime\src\modules\empty-module.js\index(.native|.native.js|.js|.native.jsx|.jsx|.native.json|.json|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx).
Error: Unable to resolve module C:\Users\{myusername}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\metro-runtime\src\modules\empty-module.js from C:\DATA\Projects\iDOL\Code\{myappname}\_:

None of these files exist:
  * ..\..\..\..\..\Users\{myusername}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\metro-runtime\src\modules\empty-module.js(.native|.native.js|.js|.native.jsx|.jsx|.native.json|.json|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * ..\..\..\..\..\Users\{myusername}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\metro-runtime\src\modules\empty-module.js\index(.native|.native.js|.js|.native.jsx|.jsx|.native.json|.json|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\Users\{myusername}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:152:15)
    at ModuleResolver._getEmptyModule (C:\Users\{myusername}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:50:26)
    at ModuleResolver._getFileResolvedModule (C:\Users\{myusername}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:219:21)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\Users\{myusername}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:148:19)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Users\{myusername}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:264:43)
    at Object.resolve (C:\Users\{myusername}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:170:21)
    at resolveDependencies (C:\Users\{myusername}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\graphOperations.js:466:33)
    at processModule (C:\Users\{myusername}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\graphOperations.js:232:31)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

A thing I don't understand: the installed react native version is "0.67.2", but when I try to create the resources I can see "Welcome to Metro v0.72.3". I don't know if this has sense.

The file `C:\Users\{myusername}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\metro-runtime\src\modules\empty-module.js` exits.

Do you know why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the cli was corrupted. I solved the problem installing it with `--force`:

```
npm install -g react-native-cli @react-native-community/cli --force
```